# $1_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{A_n}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

If $A_n$, $n=1,2,...$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, show that for $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n$
$$1_{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{A_n}$$

---

I have no idea on how to approach such a problem. I know that the indicator function will take on the value $1$ if $x\in A_i$ and $0$ if $x\notin A_i$ and that disjoint means that $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $j\neq i$. Now that would mean that the LHS would take on $1$ and $0$ and also the RHS - though I am thinking that since they are disjoint there will be one such $x$ only so that the indicator functions takes on the value $1$ and $0$ for the rest since they are disjoint. Now, to show the equality how do I proceed?

Comment: You take an arbitrary point $x$ and evaluate both sides. The value of the left hand side is $1$ if $x\in\bigcup_n A_n$ and $0$ otherwise. Assume the latter. Then $x\notin \bigcup_n A_n$. This implies that for all $n$, $x\notin A_n$. Therefore, $1_{A_n}(x)=0$ and the right hand side is $0$ too. Assume that the left hand side is $1$. Then, $x\in\bigcup_n A_n$. There must be some $n_0$ such that $x\in A_{n_0}$. Sine the $A_n$ are disjoint, then that $n_0$ is unique. Therefore, $1_{A_n}(x)$ is zero for all $n$ except for $n=n_0$. So, the right hand side is also $1$.

Comment: @Boxwood Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: Another tactic: show it by induction for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}1_{\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i} = 1_{\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i}$$ (under the assumptions given) to conclude the result.

Comment: @Boxwood How does that in any way address my concern?

Comment: @Boxwood This is the third time your reasoning to this exact question from me is a link to a random worddump. That's not constructive, and not appreciated in any way.

Comment: @Arthur My VoiceOver is not selecting the right link. I think it is [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.06979.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A:=\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

If $x\in A$, then $1_A(x)=1$. Since the union is disjoint, $x$ must be in $A_k$ for exactly one $k$. Thus
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{A_n}(x)=1_{A_k}(x)=1
$$

If $x\not\in A$, then $1_A(x)=0$. But since $x$ is not in $A$, $x$ cannot be in $A_n$ for any $n$. Hence, the $1_{A_n}(x)=0$ for each $n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{A_n}(x)=0$.